# Python key sorting

Tags: python-2.7

Im taking an online beginner course through google on python 2, and I cannot figure out the answer to one of the questions.  Here it is and thanks in advance for your help!

```
# A. match_ends
# Given a list of strings, return the count of the number of
# strings where the string length is 2 or more and the first
# and last chars of the string are the same.
# Note: python does not have a ++ operator, but += works.

def match_ends(words):
  a = []
  for b in words:

retun
```

I tried a few different things.  This is just where i left off on my last attempt, and decided to ask for help.  I have spent more time thinking about this than i care to mention

Comment: Can you post your attempt please?

Comment: thats as far as i got.  I tried a couple different things.  There is something thats just not clicking in my brain.  Im right on the verge of solving it but i feel like im just missing one key component.

Answer (score 0):

You should go through the course materials carefully. This can be solved easily if you have a beginner level understanding of Python. See the following code snippet:

```
def match_ends(words):
  count = 0
  for word in words:
        if len(word) >= 2 and word[0] == word[-1]:
            count += 1
  return count
```